# Issue with pseudo-element based on hover highlight not working properly

Tags: html, css

I want to add animated highlight of links and want to achieve this with pseudo element. When there are multiple links, if the link breaks line the link in the new line does not highlight. In Chrome dev tools the link looks like taking space on the whole parent container for some reason, which might be the issue. Can you help me track down what's the issue with this aproach?

Here is the distilled code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    #container {
        width: 250px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    a {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    a::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    }
    a:hover::before {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p>
        <a href="">First Link</a>,
        <a href="">Second Link</a>,
        <a href="">Third Link</a>,
        <a href="">Fourth Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what gets highlighted in dev tools for the Fourth Link:
[image]

Comment: If you _don't_ need the links themselves to (potentially) break into multiple lines, then adding `display: inline-block` would be an easy fix.

Comment: I don't and indeed this works. I stil do not understand why it didn't :)

Comment: Not an explanation, an observation: If you give the pseudo element some content: 'abc' you'll see that for the 4th anchor element it is to the righthand side of the container, bottom (so the underline itself is not seen).